# QuickFixN HotSpotFX MarketData cracker wanted

Tags: c#, quickfix

Save me reinventing the wheel.

Does any have and maybe willing to share a cSharp cracker for HotSpotFX MarketData. I want something that takes the FromApp messages and parses them into a suitable form for storing the Prices on disk.d
Moderators please note. I know this is not strictly a programming question but I don't know where else to put this. If there is a more suitable forum let me know please.

Comment: This is a pure coding question and nobody will supply you the code, that will be infringement and amount to stealing, which will be illegal.

Comment: I don't believe so. I think you might be confusing the term "cracking" which is QuickFix speak for PARSING messages

Comment: `FromApp messages and parses them into a suitable form for storing the Prices` -. How is this then done ? Isn't that done using code ?

Comment: @DumbCoder - it's only infringement if the giver does not have the right to give it.

Answer (score 0):

This stuff is basic FIX, easy to do, and you'd be better off listening to FromApp and writing your own persistence layer into a database, like MySQL, not disk...

If you then wanted disk then take a report from your database.